# I don't understand the usefulness of parameter arrays?

Tags: c#

Parameter arrays allow a variable number of arguments to be passed into a method:

```
    static void Method(params int[] array)
    {}
```

But I fail to see their usefulness, since same result could be achieved by specifying a parameter of particular array type:

```
    static void Method(int[] array)
    {}
```

So what benefits ( if any ) does parameter array have over value parameter of array type?

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The benefit is that the compiler creates the array automatically for you:

```
string coor = String.Concat("x=", x, ", y=", y);
```

The code that is generated for you is actually:

```
string coor = String.Concat(new string [] { "x=", x, ", y=", y });
```

You even get the best of both worlds. If you happen to have your data in an array, you can pass it to a method that has a `params` parameter.

Answer (score 7):

It's just a code readability thing. For example, string.Format:

```
string value = string.Format("SomeFormatString", param1, param2, param3, param4.... param999);
```

It could be written like this in a different lifetime:

```
string value = string.Format("SomeFormatString", new string[] { param1, param2, param3 });
```

In the end, it's just syntactic sugar to make the code easier to read and easier to understand.

Answer (score 6):

In the second example, the consumer can't call it using

```
MyType.Method(1, 2, 3)
```

Answer (score 2):

I for one much prefer to write

```
Method(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
```

instead of

```
Method(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5} );
```

Answer (score 1):

It's how they're called.

In the first example, with params, you can call `Method(1,2,3,4,5);`

In the second example, without params, you have to call it `Method(new [] {1,2,3,4,5});`